# How does the linux kernel support dns changes for resolving domain names?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, resolv.conf

In linux, the dns servers are configured in /etc/resolv.conf, without going into userspace implementations, how are changes to this file supposed to propagate to the many consumers of domain names?

Comment: You seem to be confusing Linux the kernel, and Gnu/Linux the Operating System.

Comment: In what way? I have made no reference to any gnu specific implementation. The man pages of resolv.conf clearly mark it as written by linux kernel, linking to kernel.org. while gnu/linux tools like cp always specify GNU/Linux

Comment: Gnu is a set of programs, and a project: to write a Unix operating system, that is Free (see free software definition). And the man page I just looked at says that resolve.conf is used by a set of routines in the C library that provide access to the Internet Domain Name System (DNS). And that this library is probably `glibc`.

Answer (score 4):

The linux kernel doesn't care about DNS.

User space cares, and typically looks up each name each time it is needed, possibly with some local caching.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. Any idea why? This looks like it would be a basic kernel feature

Comment: There is some code regarding dns queries in the kernel https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/dns_resolver?h=v5.6-rc5

Comment: There are a variety of philosophies as to what goes in a kernel. 1)Only put it there if it has to be there. 2) Put it there if, it has to be there or it will significantly improve performance.

Comment: The code that is referenced doesn't do DNS queries, it calls user space to do the query. The Kconfig says "If in doubt say N" so this is probably not compiled into you kernel.

Comment: The manpages confusion should probably be addressed.  It's all to do with the particular manual entry in question _coming from ISC's BIND_ and being republished as part of a project to write manual pages _that is not part of the kernel_ and whose only connection to even the _word_ kernel is one single URL at the bottom of the page pointing to the project's WWW site.